# How to add a component to VueJs3 app before mounting

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have set up **chartApp** as my application like so:

```
const chartApp = {
        data(){
            ...
        },
        methods:{
            async init() {
                //await async menthod
            }
        }
    }

const app = Vue.createApp(chartApp).mount('#app');
app.init();
```

Which works.

I can go into the browser console, type app. and see the init function

I'm wanting to register a component. I've tried to set the app like this:

```
const chartApp = {
    data(){
        ...
    },
    methods:{
        async init() {
            //await async menthod
        }
    }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(chartApp);
app.component('my-component', {
    template:'<div>hello</div>'
});
app.mount('#app');
app.init();
```

But I receive an error stating

> app.init is not a function

this time when I look at my browser console, and type app. ...I see an option to mount / unmount, but not init function.

I thought, maybe the app had failed to mount, so I tried:
app.mount('#app')
in the console but received the following warning:

> App has already been mounted.

How am I able to register a component please? VueJs3 version is 3.2.16.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1st case you are calling your `init` method on the result of the `mount` function.

But in the second case on the result of `createApp`....which is a [very different object](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/5aa425580808d0588aef12ead81c91f7147e1042/packages/runtime-core/src/apiCreateApp.ts#L28)

Do this:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp(chartApp);
app.component('my-component', {
    template:'<div>hello</div>'
});
const mountedApp = app.mount('#app');
mountedApp.init();
```